# Unity: InputField created from Script via TMP_DefaultControls doesn't have carat

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create InputFields in my Unity app via Script. Here is the code for the same.

```
TMP_DefaultControls.Resources uiResources = new TMP_DefaultControls.Resources();
GameObject uiInputField = TMP_DefaultControls.CreateInputField(uiResources);
uiInputField.name = "MyInput";
uiInputField.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
```

This is working fine and my field is created and works okay. But the Carat is missing. When I create an InputField via the editor, the carat is generated when I run the app, but not in this case. There is the option to create the carat manually and add it to the InputField, but I feel that a better way must exist. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can this help : [InputField text and carat don't show up after build](https://forum.unity.com/threads/inputfield-text-and-carat-dont-show-up-after-build.509134/)